# Practical Implementation for Data Warehouse

Tags: database, data-warehouse, etl, pentaho

Data warehousing seems to be a big trend these days, and is very interesting to me. I'm trying to acquaint myself with its concepts, and am having a problem "seeing the forest through the trees" because all of the data warehouse models and descriptions I can find online are *theoretical*, but don't gives examples with actual technologies being used. I'm a contextual learner, so abstracted, theoretical explanations don't really help me out all that much.

Now there seem to be many "data warehousing models", but all of them seem to have some similar characteristics. There is ually an "**ODS**" (operational data store that aggregates data from multiple sources into the same place. A process known as "ETL" then converts data in this ODS into a "data vault", and again into "data" and/or "strategy marts."

Can someone provide an example of the technologies that would be used for each of these components (ODS, ETL, data vault, data/strategy marts)?

It sounds like the ODS could just be any ordinary database, but the data vault seems to have some special things going on because it is used by these "marts" to pull data from.

ETL is the biggest thing I'm choking on by far.  Is this a language? A framework? An algorithm?

I think once I see a concrete example of what's going on at each step of the way, I'll finally *get it*. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETL is a process. The abbreviation stands for Extract-Transform-Load which describes what is being done with data during the process. The process can be implemented anywhere where you need to create a bridge between two systems with differenet data formats. First, you need to pull (exract) data from a source system (database, flat files, web service etc.), Then data are being processed (transform) to comply with format of a target storage (again it can vary: databases, files, API calls). During the transform step, further actions can be performed on the data set as enrichment with data from other sources, cleansing and improving its quality. The last step is loading transformed data into a target storage.

Typically, an ETL process is employed for loading a datawarehouse, migrating data from one system or database to another during moving from a legacy system to new one, synchronizing data between two or more systems. It is also used as an intermediate layer in broader MDM and BI solutions.

In terms of specific software, there are many ETL tools on the market ranging from robust solutions from big players as Informatica, IBM DataStage, Oracle Data Integrator, to more affordable and open source providers as CloverETL, Talend, or Pentaho. The most of these tools offer a GUI where flow and processing of data is defined through diagrams.

Comment: Thanks @Jan! What about these so-called "data vaults" and "data marts"? Are these just databases with special properties? Or are they specialized software systems?

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and later the ETL tool is called SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services). If you install at least the Standard version of the SQL Server you get the [Business Intelligence Developer Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx) with which you can design your data flows. Basically what an ETL tool does is take data from one or more sources (tables, flat files, ...) then transform it (add columns, join, filter, map to different data types, etc.) and finally store it again to one or more tables or files.

To get a basic understanding of how something works you can watch e.g. [this video](http://midnightdba.itbookworm.com/VidPages/SSISBasics/SSISBasics.aspx) or [this one](http://midnightdba.itbookworm.com/VidPages/SSISGroundZero1/SSISGroundZero1.aspx) (both from midnightdba). They're a bit lengthy, but you get an idea. They certainly helped me in understanding the basic functionality of an ETL tool.

Unfortunately I have not yet digged into other platforms or tools.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend checking out some of the books by Ralph Kimball and Margy Ross (The Data Warehouse Toolkit, The Data Warehouse Lifecycle Toolkit) for an introduction to data warehousing.

My company's data warehouse is built using the Oracle Warehouse Builder tool for ETL.  The OWB is a GUI tool that generates PL/SQL code on the database to manipulate the data.  After manipulation and cleansing, the data is published to an Oracle datamart.  The datamart is a database instance that users access for ad-hoc querying via Oracle Discoverer (Java software).